# Ordenando arrays com Bubble Sort

Tags: javascript, algoritmo, revisão-de-código, bubblesort

Estou resolvendo uma questão do meu curso a qual eu preciso usar um algoritmo de ordenação de vetores com base no algoritmo Bubble Sort.

Fazendo um resumo prévio, a lógica consiste em passar por todos os valores do array, em pares, comparando um ao outro e verificando qual é maior. O número maior sempre irá para a direita, trocando com o valor menor, passando assim sempre o maior número para a extrema direita. Após passar por todos os números do vetor e ordenar a primeira vez, o laço de repetição se repete pela quantidade de números do array até ordenar todos os valores.

Eu escrevi esse código e ele está funcional:

```js
let bubble = [82, 76, 6, 52, 45, 38, 24, 14, 54, 85, 143, 98, 65, 512, 96, 12, 4, 79];
    
function bubbleSort () {
    for (let i = 0; i < bubble.length; i++) {
        if (bubble[i] > bubble[i +1]) {
            let v1 = bubble[i]
            let v2 = bubble[i +1] 
            bubble[i] = v2
            bubble[i +1] = v1
        }
    }
}

for (let j = 0; j < bubble.length ; j++) {
    bubbleSort();
}

console.log(bubble)
```

Saída do código:

```
[
   4,  6,  12,  14, 24, 38, 45,
  52, 54,  65,  76, 79, 82, 85,
  96, 98, 143, 512
]
```

Como ainda estou aprendendo, gostaria de saber como eu poderia refatorar o código para que eu não precisasse usar uma `function` para fazer a segunda repetição do laço. Tentei colocar for dentro de for mas ele acabou me retornando `undefined` quando imprimo a saída no console. Podem me dar dicas para que o código fique mais legível e simples?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Se você quiser remover a função "intermediária" `bubbleSort`, basta "realocar" o laço `for` que está no corpo dela para dentro do `for` principal. Assim:

```js
function bubbleSort(originalArray) {
  const bubble = [...originalArray];

  // Este é o laço que antes estava no escopo global:
  for (let j = 0; j < bubble.length ; j++) {

    // Este é o laço que antes estava dentro da função:
    for (let i = 0; i < bubble.length; i++) {
      if (bubble[i] > bubble[i +1]) {
        let v1 = bubble[i];
        let v2 = bubble[i +1];
        bubble[i] = v2;
        bubble[i +1] = v1;
      }
    }
  }
  
  return bubble;
}

console.log(bubbleSort([4, 2, 5, 3, 1]));
```

E funcionará como esperado. Note também que eu "extraí" todo o código para dentro de uma única função, coincidentemente chamada `bubbleSort`. Assim, poderemos chamar a mesma função diversas vezes passando diferentes arrays para serem classificados. Também fiz uma cópia do *array* passado como argumento para evitar mutações na lista original.

O problema do código acima é que ele sempre fará `N^2` iterações, sendo `N` a quantidade de elementos do *array* a ser sorteado. Isso porque você não implementou nenhum meio de verificar se o *array* já foi devidamente classificado. Para ilustrar isso, vejamos o exemplo abaixo:

```js
function bubbleSort(originalArray) {
  const bubble = [...originalArray];
  
  let counter = 0;

  for (let j = 0; j < bubble.length ; j++) {
    for (let i = 0; i < bubble.length; i++) {
      counter++;
      
      if (bubble[i] > bubble[i +1]) {
        let v1 = bubble[i];
        let v2 = bubble[i +1];
        bubble[i] = v2;
        bubble[i +1] = v1;
      }
    }
  }
  
  console.log(counter);
  return bubble;
}

bubbleSort([1, 2, 3, 4, 5]);
// Imprimirá 25 no console (25 iterações foram feitas).
```

Note que, mesmo que já devidamente sorteada, uma lista será varrida (desnecessariamente) 25 vezes, isto é, o quadrado do seu número de elementos.

Um simples *booleano* pode resolver esse problema. Usaremos ele para indicar, do "laço interno", quando uma mudança for realizada. Desse modo, a partir do "laço externo", poderemos verificar se uma "troca" foi feita em alguma das iterações do "laço interno". No caso disso não tiver acontecido, podemos assumir que o *array* já foi sorteado. Assim:

```js
function bubbleSort(originalArray) {
  // Copiamos o array para evitar modificações no array original:
  const array = [...originalArray];

  for (let i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
    // Booleano que usaremos para verificar se houve troca:
    let swapped = false;

    for (let j = 0; j < array.length; j++) {
      const current = array[j];
      const next = array[j + 1];

      if (current > next) {
        array[j + 1] = current;
        array[j] = next;

        // Marcamos `swapped` como `true` para indicar que houve troca.
        swapped = true;
      }
    }

    // Se não houve nenhuma troca nesta iteração, significa
    // que o array já está sorteado. Podemos, então, sair.
    if (!swapped) {
      break;
    }
  }

  return array;
}

console.log(bubbleSort([4, 2, 5, 3, 1]));
```

Note agora que, mesmo que um *array* já devidamente sorteado seja passado, ao invés de 25, somente ocorrerão 5 iterações (que é o melhor cenário). Podemos verificar isso adicionando o contador:

```js
function bubbleSort(originalArray) {
  // Copiamos o array para evitar modificações no array original:
  const array = [...originalArray];

  let counter = 0;

  for (let i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
    // Booleano que usaremos para verificar se houve troca:
    let swapped = false;

    for (let j = 0; j < array.length; j++) {
      counter++;

      const current = array[j];
      const next = array[j + 1];

      if (current > next) {
        array[j + 1] = current;
        array[j] = next;

        // Marcamos `swapped` como `true` para indicar que houve troca.
        swapped = true;
      }
    }

    // Se não houve nenhuma troca nesta iteração, significa
    // que o array já está sorteado. Podemos, então, sair.
    if (!swapped) {
      break;
    }
  }

  console.log(counter);
  return array;
}

bubbleSort([1, 2, 3, 4, 5]);
// Imprimirá 5 no console (5 iterações foram feitas — esse é o improvável melhor cenário).
```

Para o pior cenário, os `N^2` ainda serão necessários, já que é uma característica intrínseca do algoritmo.

Algumas [otimizações a mais](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bubble_sort#Optimizing_bubble_sort) podem ser feitas também. Mas, no geral, esse não é um algoritmo eficiente e existem alternativas mais performáticas. A [outra resposta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/478177/69296) dá uma explicação um pouco mais detalhada sobre essa otimização.

Comment: Era exatamente isso que eu precisava, Luiz! Não estou ainda pensando em implementações melhores pois estou passando pelo caminho das pedras antes antes de chegar em recursos mais eficientes, seguindo a linha do meu curto. Me ajudou bastante, e a implementação com o boolean matou essa questão de passar diversas vezes pelos números mesmo demais de estarem sorteados. Ainda assim, percebi que não houve redução do tempo de execução do código (antes 0.05~, agora 0,05~), existe alguma explicação para isso?

Comment: Provavelmente o número de elementos é tão pequeno que faz pouca diferença. A adição do _boolean_ evita _algumas_ iterações adicionais, mas em quase nada ajuda para contornar a ineficiência intrínseca desse algoritmo (`O(N^2)` não é muito bom, no pior dos casos...). Ah, e como você é novo no site, não esqueça de verificar no [tour] a melhor forma de dizer obrigado. Bem-vindo. :-)

Comment: @DiegoAugustoF. Tem que ver também como vc está medindo (eu uso sites como o https://jsbench.me) - e também coloquei [uma resposta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/478177/112052) com outra alternativa (mas não vai melhorar tanto assim, bubble sort é ineficiente por definição)

Answer (score 8):

A primeira coisa é colocar todo o algoritmo dentro da função. Se os 2 *loops* fazem parte do algoritmo, então ambos deveriam estar lá, você não deveria depender de um *loop* externo para que a função funcione corretamente.

Outro detalhe é que a função, da forma que foi feita, acessa o array `bubble` que foi criado fora da função. Ou seja, só funciona para aquele array. Seria melhor que ela recebesse o array como parâmetro, assim ela funciona para qualquer array:

```js
function bubbleSort(array) {
    for (let i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
        for (let j = i + 1; j < array.length; j++) {
            if (array[i] > array[j]) {
                let aux = array[i];
                array[i] = array[j];
                array[j] = aux;
            }
        }
    }
}

let numeros = [82, 76, 6, 52, 45, 38, 24, 14, 54, 85, 143, 98, 65, 512, 96, 12, 4, 79];
bubbleSort(numeros);
console.log(numeros);

// posso reaproveitar a função para ordenar outro array
let outroArray = [1, 5, 34, 2, 6, 7, 8, 12];
bubbleSort(outroArray);
console.log(outroArray);
```

Também fiz uma alteração nos *loops*. Não faz sentido tanto `i` quanto `j` começarem do zero (pois aí estarei comparando o elemento com ele mesmo). Outro detalhe é que, depois da primeira iteração, o primeiro elemento com certeza já será o menor de todos, então não tem porque compará-lo novamente nas iterações seguintes. Sendo assim, o *loop* interno sempre começa em `i + 1` (em vez de sempre começar do zero).

Claro que isso não vai ser *aquela* otimização, já que bubble sort em si não é o algoritmo mais eficiente de todos, e para arrays pequenos a diferença será imperceptível. Mas de qualquer forma, [fica mais rápido](https://jsbench.me/s0kgghnf6z/1).

E vale notar que esta função modifica o array. Se quiser que ele não modifique o array original, faça como a [outra resposta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/478174/112052) indicou.

---

Também coloquei ponto-e-vírgula no final das linhas. Pode parecer "frescura", e sei que o JavaScript "aceita" o código sem ponto e vírgula e "funciona", mas isso evita algumas situações bizarras que podem ocorrer se você não usá-los, como [essa](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1169596) e [essa](/q/432960/112052) (veja mais sobre isso [aqui](/q/3341/112052)).

Answer (score 0):

Acredito que a forma mais rápida é percorrendo até chegar no final dessa ordenação:

```
let bubble = [82, 76, 6, 52, 45, 38, 24, 14, 54, 85, 143, 98, 65, 512, 96, 12, 4, 79];
    
function bubbleSort(arr) {
         let t = arr.length;
        while (t) {
            for (let i in arr) {
                if (arr[ i ] > arr[i + 1]) {
                    let temp = arr[ i ];
                    arr[ i ] = arr[i + 1];
                    arr[i + 1] = temp
                }
            }
            t--;
        }
        return arr;
    }
    
    console.log(bubbleSort(bubble))
```

Mas se quiser melhorar, pode fazer isso:

```
let bubble = [82, 76, 6, 52, 45, 38, 24, 14, 54, 85, 143, 98, 65, 512, 96, 12, 4, 79];
 
function bubbleSort(arr) {
    return arr.sort((a, b) => {
        return (a < b+1) ? -1 : 1
 });
}
    console.log(bubbleSort(bubble))
```